# Passing data from Grandparent to child angular 4

Tags: angular

Is there any other way of passing data from grandparent to a child component in angular without using a data service (the child is dependent of data that the grandparent gets from the api) ? If so can you help me with an example ?

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Comment: this does not answer my question

Comment: component interaction lets you pass data from one component to a child component. If this is not what you want, please clarify the question or add some relevant code.

Comment: the question is related to grandparent-child relationship not parent-child. the question is as clear as possible

Comment: You can pass the data from the grandparent to the parent then from the parent to the child. If you don't want to do this, you can use the @Host() decorator https://angular.io/api/core/Host to inject the grandparent into the child and let the child access the data in the grandparent.

Comment: thank you for your answer, you clarified my concerns